# Can't start Eclipse (JUNO)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

So, yesterday, I was fine-ly developing android apps in my Eclipse Juno. After I want to test and "Run As > Android Application" I just realized that I haven't start the Emulator first, then I started the Emulator, but apparently Two Emu-s shows up, I then closed both (dunno why). And then the menace begin.

Even the Emulator closed, Launching 100% still shown on bottom-right of the Eclipse. I then close the Eclipse, but since the Launching-100%-stuff still not done, AND CAN'T BE STOPPED, I then shut it down via Task Manager, and started Eclipse again.

Shockingly, the Eclipse shown error, can't be opened and tell me to read the log file. I read it, but can't understand. I then restarted Windows, and then the Eclipse doing fine. I then starting a device first, once finished, I Run As > Android Application. But the result is the same as above Launching 100% for a long time.

I then create a new project, and copy all the inside of the class into a file with similar project created in the project.

But the problem is nowhere gone. There is the same error as above. Also, when I read the error log and then there is message pop up : "Failed to load properties file for project *_*_". I then searched, and find that the debug.keystore need to be deleted and then clean the project to regenerate the debug.keystore. But, there is NONE debug.keystore created, and when I Run As > Android Application again, the result is the same, but there is additional error log :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-05-24 23:29:18.604
!MESSAGE Unable to create part

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.filebuffers 4 0 2013-05-24 23:29:18.623
!MESSAGE The file does not exist.
```

Do any of you have the resolve to this problem? Thanks.

Tools used : Eclipse Juno, Android 2.3.3 Emulator, Windows 8 Professional

Note : I update nothing, and not doing something bad with Eclipse

Comment: Can I tell you a tip? Try to use the new android studio based on Intellij: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html
It plays very well with android enviroment

Comment: (I'm using windows 8) I can't open the studio. Tried "run as admin" also, but no good. Any clue?

Comment: I'm using windows 8 also and didn't have any problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse :
Reinstall sdk and adt. And it's gone well.

Android Studio in windows 8:
Right click on the My Computer > Environment Variables > New (in System, not user) > Name : JAVA_HOME > path : [your jdk folder] > ok. Then it's running.